# How to do sapply to several columns in data frame r and have the result in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
5 2 6 7 2
9 1 5 7 6
2 3 5 7 1
```

And a function which needs to use val2, val3, val4 values from each row

```
aFunction <- function(v2,v3,v4) {
    result = v2*2/v3 + max(max(v2,v3),v4)
    return(result)
}
```

I need the result of this function to be stored in a new column in the data frame:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 result
5 2 4 7 2 8
9 3 2 7 6 10
2 10 5 7 1 14
```

But I'm not sure how to do this,

I've thought of doing

```
result = apply(df,function(x) {aFunction(x$val2,x$val3,x$val4)})
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You should build a general function.

`newFunction <- function(a, b,c) { result= a*2/b +c; return(result)}`

Get that max for the three columns.

`newConstant <- max(max(df$val2, df$val3),df$val4)`

Use sapply to apply to the column and assign to a new column.

`df$val5 <- sapply(df, newFunction, df$val2, df$val3, newConstant)`

I am not able to run this solution right now, but that setup should work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` package which uses natural verbs to go through the process. Using the second set of numbers in your example, here's what you can do:

```
zz <- "val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
1 5 2 4 7 2
2 9 3 2 7 6
3 2 10 5 7 1"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE) # Creates the dataframe

library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = (val2 * 2 / val3) + max(val2, val3, val4))
```

The command takes your data and indicates that it will evaluate everything `rowwise()` which is important so you don't get the maximum values for each row in your dataframe. Finally, `mutate()` makes a new variable that is based on the function you supplied.

To save the data to a new element use `newdata <-` in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the columns differently when calling your function. This solution works for your example:

```
df<-read.table(text="val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
           5 2 6 7 2
           9 3 2 7 6
           2 10 5 7 1",header=T)

aFunction <- function(v2,v3,v4) {
 v2*2/v3 + max(max(v2,v3),v4)
}

df$results<-apply(df,1,function(x) {aFunction(x[2],x[3],x[4])})
```

Note that, even if this answer specifically address your problem, more elegant solutions were provided by the other answers.